# How to introduce yourself to a new contact online?

Tags: communication

Long story short, I've been given contact details (LinkedIn) for a person whom is reasonably senior in a company by a current colleague. The person in question is a alumni of my current employer, and my university, and works in the same industry as me.

My current colleague recommended I contact them and see whether there would be any opportunities for me there, as we have a lot in common, and I'd be interested in working there.

How do I go about introducing myself without it coming across as an unsolicited job request and is there anything in particular I should avoid saying?

Edit: The potential contact lives and works overseas, and I only have his LinkedIn details, so a face to face meeting sadly isn't possible. I have means and the required documentation to live and work in said country.

Comment: Email, Phone, LinkedIn?

Comment: I mentioned they were LinkedIn details in the OP.

Answer (score 5):

> How do I go about introducing myself without it coming across as an unsolicited job request

**It is an unsolicited job request.** If you go directly to the contact, there is no getting around the fact that you do not know this person, and it might be a tad awkward. From what you've described, you haven't even met them, face-to-face or otherwise.

The best thing you can do is **ask for an introduction** from your colleague. You can expand your network and connections via your existing network, and this sounds like a great chance to give it a shot.

After the introduction is made, over email, LinkedIn, or otherwise, take the reigns and initiate something with your new connection. If you can, offer to buy them lunch or coffee. Do some research on their work history, projects, expertise, etc. and have a few professional or technical questions ready to show that you're interested in getting to know them better. Some people are more receptive to this than others, but regardless of the outcome, networking and relationship-building is a valuable skill to have in the workplace.

Comment: I've added a bit of detail to the question. An actual introduction would obviously be ideal, I suggested this to my colleague and he didn't seem to see why it was necessary.

Comment: If you're still intent on getting to know them, try something like an email or LinkedIn conversation. Collaborate on a project together. Reach out in some way. Unfortunately, though, your chances of making a major connection are slim with online-only aquaintences.